# Two Laravel projects on one VPS with Apache

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, server

I got two Laravel projects, set on an Apache server. One of the project has it's own domain, let's say it's `mydomain.dev`, other one's domain is just `vps-address.com/project2`.

Now, the problem is, when I enter `mydomain.dev`, I see project1, as it should be. But when I enter `mydomain.dev/project2` I see the other project, but I want to make it inaccessible that way. Also, when I enter `vps-address.com/project1` or `vps-address.com/project2` I get 500 Internal Error, with an error in error.log saying:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

This is my folder structure:

```
/var/www/html/project1
/var/www/html/project2
```

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
Alias /project1 /var/www/html/project1/public
Alias /project2 /var/www/html/project2/public

<Directory /var/www/html/project1>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/project2>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName vps-address.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1/public
    ServerName mydomain.dev

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName vps-address.com/project2
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project2/public
</VirtualHost>
```

And my .htaccess in both of the /public folders:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would like to make project2 accessible only by this address: `vps-address.com/project2`, not `mydomain.dev/project2`, and the project1 to be accessible only: `mydomain.dev`.

Is that possible to do with Laravel and Apache2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this config:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/html/project1>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/project2>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName vps-address.com
    Alias /project2 /var/www/html/project2/public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1/public
    ServerName mydomain.dev

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:**
Also change the .htaccess in the `/var/www/html/project2/public` to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project2/

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `mydomain.dev` now works perfectly and doesn't show the project2. But, when I visit `vps-address.com/project2` I still get this error:

`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Also you need to check your App Url inside `.env` file in `/var/www/html/project2`

Comment: Everything works as it should! Thank you very much!